# The Baire space is homogeneous,

Tags: general-topology, homogeneous-spaces, the-baire-space

it's kwown that the Cantor space $2^{\omega}$ is a homogeneous topological space (because it is a topological group). Does anyone have any idea why $\omega^{\omega}$ is a homogeneous topological space?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x,y\in\omega^\omega$, for each $n\in\omega$ let $f_n:\omega\to\omega$ be the map the interchanges $x_n$ and $y_n$ and leaves everything else fixed. Let

$$h:\omega^\omega\to\omega^\omega:z\mapsto\langle f_n(z_n):n\in\omega\rangle\,;$$

then $h(x)=y$, and $h$ is an autohomeomorphism of $\omega^\omega$.

Another approach is to note that $\omega^\omega$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Z^\omega$, and that the product topology on $\Bbb Z^\omega$ is the same as the order topology induced by the lexicographic order $\preceq$. Now let $\sigma,\tau\in\mathbb{Z}^\omega$, and define $\delta\in\mathbb{Z}^\omega$ by $\delta(n)=\tau(n)-\sigma(n)$. Then the translation $$s:\mathbb{Z}^\omega\to\mathbb{Z}^\omega:\varphi\mapsto\varphi+\delta=\langle\varphi(n)+\delta(n):n\in\omega\rangle$$ is an order-automorphism of $\langle\mathbb{Z}^\omega,\preceq\rangle$ taking $\sigma$ to $\tau$ and thus also an autohomeomorphism of $\Bbb Z^\omega$ with the order topology induced by $\preceq$.

Comment: Maybe I'm not really understanding the definition of $f_n$, because it doesn't seem to me that $h$ is injective.

Comment: @gaam2296: If $u,z\in\omega^\omega$, and $h(u)=h(z)$, then $f_n(u_n)=f_n(z_n)$ for each $n\in\omega$. And each $f_n$ is a bijection of $\omega$ onto itself, so $u_n=z_n$ for each $n\in\omega$, and therefore $u=z$.

Comment: Ahh I understand the definition of $f_n$, thanks.

Comment: @gaam2296: You’re welcome.

Comment: I have a question, suppose that there is $n_0\in\omega$ such that $x_{n_{0}}\not=y_{n_{0}}$ then $f_{n_{0}} (y_{n_{0}) = y_{n_{0}}$ and             
$f_{n_{0}} (x_{n_{0}}) = y_{n_{0}$, in this case the function is not injective?

Comment: @gaam2296: The functions $f_n$ are injective, and therefore so is $h$. If $x_{n_0}\ne y_{n_0}$ then $$f_{n_0}(y_{n_0})=x_{n_0}\ne y_{n_0}=f_{n_0}(x_{n_0})\,.$$

Comment: Well, the following function is a bijection of $\omega$ onto itself. $$
 \begin{array}{lcccl}
 f_{n} & : & \omega & \longrightarrow & \omega\\
 & & m & \longrightarrow &  f_{n}(m)=  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  y_{n} & \mbox{if} & m=x_{n}
  \\\\
  x_{n} &  \mbox{if} & m=y_{n}
    \\\\
  m &  \mbox{if} & m\in X\setminus\{x_{n},y_{n}\}   \end{array}
  \right.
 \end{array}
 $$

Comment: This is the function that you mentioned. I think that by doing the same, you can prove that $2^{\omega}$ is homogeneous, right?

Comment: @gaam2296: Yes, the same idea works just as well to show that the Cantor set is homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian M. Scott.

Comment: @gaam2296: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It's also a topological group, just view it as $\Bbb Z^\omega$ in the obvious coordinatewise group operation. $\Bbb Z \simeq \omega$ topologically after all.